# Send a command in keil as soon as Breakpint is hit

Tags: keil

I want to store a variable every time a breakpoints is hit, while i am running a test. Any idea how can i automate the task??

Or How can we monitor keil via python or any other script language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Breakpoint dialog](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_db_dbg_breakpnts.htm) to run commands when you hit a breakpoint.

[image: keil breakpoint dialog]

Comment: I have one more question , i am saving a variable by "SAVE temp1.hex temp_array,&temp_array[0]+sizeof(temp_array)" . if i want to increment temp1.hex at hit how to achieve same??

Comment: @yogeshsingh You could call a function that selects a different hex. This is far beyond how much time I've spent in debug commands. Sorry.